# jQuery: validate rules not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#loginForm").validate({
            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10
                },
                passwd: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 8
                }
            },
            messages: {
                email: {
                    required: "Please enter your email",
                    minlength: "Minlength has to be 10"
                },
                passwd: {
                    required: "Please enter your email",
                    minlength: "Minlength has to be 8"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                alert('valid form submit');
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

I have this in the HTML head_

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

And the jQuery above at the end before closing body tag.

Following code works perfectly fine on jsfiddle when I use      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js and
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.min.js.

but on my browser, it always goes to submit handler.
http://jsfiddle.net/4937t/

I really appreciate your time.

Comment: its working here http://jsfiddle.net/4937t/8/

Comment: exactly that's what i mentioned in question too. It works on jsfildde but same thing always goes to submit handler in my code. I am wondering if i am using script tags properly in code.
Thanks for taking a look

Comment: try removing those http: in src simply put src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js" give a try

Comment: Thanks.

But still same issue. No console errors too

Comment: okay tell me more, did you put $document.ready function after the script tags or before the script tags ? also is it working in firefox and every other browser? is the problem only with chrome or with other browser too?

Comment: I edited my question to make it even more clear. document.ready is in script tag, right before end of body tag.

Issue is with every browser.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how did you include the scripts in your html document but let me show you the working example. It works on my chrome. I guess the position of your scripts is misplaced. Hope this works

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
   <form id="loginForm">
     <input name="email" type="text"/><br/>
     <input name="passwd" type="password"/><br/>
     <input type="submit" />
   </form>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#loginForm").validate({
            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10
                },
                passwd: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 8
                }
            },
            messages: {
                email: {
                    required: "Please enter your email",
                    minlength: "Minlength has to be 10"
                },
                passwd: {
                    required: "Please enter your password",
                    minlength: "Minlength has to be 8"
                }
            },

            submitHandler: function (form) {
                alert('valid form submit');
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I still see the same issue. I am assuming that in your answer you just moved script tags from head to end of body.

Comment: I do not think so it works on my every browser. Copy this html into a new file and save it and run it. further if it does not work let me know :) and if you show us more we could help you and help you out finding the bug.

Comment: found out the problem. It's my bad. apparently, forms tag were not written and they were not working with table as expected